# Asterisk outbound calls hanging up imediatellly on Zap trunks

Tags: asterisk, trunk

The inbound calls work fine.  Outbound calls fail as follows:

```
Dial("SIP/xxxxxxxxx","ZAP/g0/14442223333|300|") 
Couldn't call g0/14442223333
Hungup 'Zap/2-1'
Everyone is busy/congested at this time
```

Same thing happens for Zap 3 and 4 (when I force it to use specific ZAP channel instead of g0).  A bit of relevant history: Something is wrong with port 1 on this card.  (Don't know what, but the previous technician advised me not to use that port because it's "broken")

Below are more details about my environment.  Thank you for you help.

zap show channel 2 to 4 show almost identical outputs

```
Channel: 2LI>
File Descriptor: 16
Span: 11*CLI>
Extension: I>
Dialing: noI>
Context: from-zaptel
Caller ID: I>
Calling TON: 0
Caller ID name:
Destroy: 0LI>
InAlarm: 0LI>
Signalling Type: FXS Kewlstart
Radio: 0*CLI>
Owner: <None>
Real: <None>>
Callwait: <None>
Threeway: <None>
Confno: -1LI>
Propagated Conference: -1
Real in conference: 0
DSP: no1*CLI>
Relax DTMF: yes
Dialing/CallwaitCAS: 0/0
Default law: ulaw
Fax Handled: no
Pulse phone: no
Echo Cancellation: 128 taps, currently OFF
Actual Confinfo: Num/0, Mode/0x0000
Actual Confmute: No
Hookstate (FXS only): Onhook
```

/proc/zaptel/1

```
Span 1: WRTDM/0 "wrtdm Board 1" (MASTER)
1 WRTDM/0/0
2 WRTDM/0/1 FXSKS (In use)
3 WRTDM/0/2 FXSKS (In use)
4 WRTDM/0/3 FXSKS (In use)
...
...
```

zaptel.conf

```
fxsks=2-4
```

zapata.conf

```
[trunkgroups]

[channels]
context=default
usecallerid=yes
hidecallerid=no
callwaiting=yes
usecallingpres=yes
callwaitingcallerid=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
canpark=yes
cancallforward=yes
callreturn=yes
busydetect=no
echocancel=yes
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
relaxdtmf=yes
rxgain=0.0
txgain=0.0
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1

immediate=no

;Sangoma A200 [slot:6 bus:1 span:1]  <wanpipe1>

context=from-zaptel

signalling = fxs_ks
group=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks exactly like a box that I fixed the other day.  Check the output from dmesg.  I have found that not have tones loaded in zaptel.conf can cause the system to be unable to place calls.